# Searching in database as You type in Text Box and auto suggest

Tags: c#-4.0, textbox

I want to fetch result from database as user type any text in text box. i have tried searching various examples and each examples carries code that fetch data from database on ON_load event and bind to data source of Text box, which is not required. I want to search only if i type and as long i am typing the result should get filtered.

In case of Text box data source, result get filtered only by starting characters or results having typed characters at start. i want to filter the results having that "typed characters" at any index of any data source item.

My database query is working fine and fetching result but if i call my function to key press event, the list behave in strange way and close down immediately after showing results and also it is only searching items starting by "Typed characters".

Is it possible to make a text box auto completion in this way?

any help or guidance will be appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Try looking at Jquery UIs autocomplete

Comment: Its Winform APP @Simon